# postgres count with like condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I am new to Postgres and trying to figure out how can i improve performance of count query with 'Like' in where clause.

```
    select    count(*) 
    from master_data 
    where name ilike '%<userInput>%';
```

I am even fine with estimated value.I googled few links and found out we can quickly get a count of entire table by using below query.

```
 SELECT reltuples AS approximate_row_count FROM pg_class WHERE relname = '<TableName>';
```

However for count with  like condition i am still not able to figure out.
Please suggest.Below are the links which i referred already.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/#dup_counts_estimated_filtered

Postgres Version - 9.5.4

Comment: `%val%` is not able to use indexes.  can you use a % on just one end `%val or val%? or use `IN` or `=` even?  More info on another question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql

Answer (score 3):

Do you must use LIKE?
Maybe it's possible to make something with IN?
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in a trigram index.  This can specifically handle `like` with wildcards.  You can start with the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input.Will explore this.